# Syndicating RSS 1.0 using WCF

Tags: wcf, rss, feed

Using the new syndication API, is there any smooth ways to read RSS 1.0 feeds? found http://www.clariusconsulting.net/blogs/kzu/comments/116679.aspx with an explination of how to read atom 0.3. Do we realy need to create our own xslt to transform the feed from RSS 1.0 to RSS 2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a XSLT in the RSS toolkit for ASP.NET  on codeplex that converts from RSS 1.0 to RSS 2.0. Using it the same way as Daniel Cazzulino is using his Atom 0.3 converter mentioned earlier

Comment: Could you please post a link to this?

Answer (score 0):

SyndicationFeed supports only Atom 1.0 and RSS 2.0.

However, you could implement your own SyndicationFeed, SyndicationItem, SyndicationFeedFormatter and SyndicationItemFormatter that understand RSS 1.0.